# Understanding clickhouse partitions

Tags: clickhouse

I see that clickhouse created multiple directories for each partition key(in each node).
Documentation says the directory name format is : partition ID_minimum block number_maximum block number_level.
Any idea what is level here?
347 distinct partition keys on one node(for one table) created 1358 directories.   (custom partitioning)

The documentation recommends not to have more than 1000 partitions. Should we just keep in mind the number of partitions keys or the number of directories also?

Also, Is there a configuration on how to control this number of directories?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding to this discussion, you can check parts and partition in the following ways:

For active partitions:

```
select count(distinct partition) from system.parts where table in ('table_name') and active
```

For active parts:

```
select count() from system.parts where table in ('table_name') and active
```

Inactive parts will be removed soon in less than 10 minutes.

To view table parts and partition together:

```
SELECT
    partition,
    name,
    active
FROM system.parts
WHERE table = 'table_name'
```

You can also read more about parts, partition and how merging happens [here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/3174#issuecomment-423435071).

Comment: Note to self. This command takes table name across the entire server. This means that if you have a table with the name "wages" in two databases (db1, db2), the partitions of both db1.wages and db2.wages will be displayed here. To delete such partition you need to DROP in a particular database! The "partition" field may match, you will think something is going wrong. Just change the "database" and do a "drop" in it

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea what is level here?

Level is a concept of [LSM-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree). MergeTree tables have mechanisms to merge data parts into bigger and deeper (w.r.t level) ones.

> Should we just keep in mind the number of partitions keys or the number of directories also?

Well I don't think that's a good idea as this method doesn't scale well. You'd better choose a low-cardinality column or expression as the partition key.

> Also, Is there a configuration on how to control this number of directories?

No explicit settings for that. But you can easily use modular expression to limit the total number of partitions.